# php script not running in WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have installed WAMP server and using port# 81 since port 80 is being used by IIS server. All works fine! `http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/` and even `http://localhost:81/?phpinfo=1`.

I have placed my website under `C:\wamp\www\` folder. On submit button I'm calling checklogin.php which chwcks for user details from DB, but all i see is the following script in browser instead of running the php code :( Need help to resolve this problem!
Any Issues with having WAMP on Windows 8?

```
<?php

$host="http://localhost:81/"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="guru_dakshina";
$tbl_name="members";  

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: How are you opening the php file ? What's the URL you're using ?

Comment: Do you have successful connection with table?

Comment: HamZa - I'm running a html file which has input form having post assigned to above script called checklongin.php

Comment: Arthur - Yes i can use phpMyadmin and created DB and tables mentioned above

Comment: Oh and what php version?Session_register is removed in php 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the host value to localhost.

try :

`$host = "localhost";`

**As we know MYSQL_* is depreciated now so better use MYSQLI_* or PDO**

Here is you code using **MYSQLI_*** , Hope it help you and i have made necessary correction needed to make it run correctly. :)

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    $host="localhost"; 
    $username="root"; 
    $password=""; 
    $db_name="guru_dakshina";
    $tbl_name="members";  

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name)or die("cannot connect"); 

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `username`='$myusername' and `password`='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($conn,$result);

    if($count==1){

    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ob_end_flush();
   ?>
```

Comment: No improvements. I can just see the script in browser on submit :(

Comment: check you page extention.. is it .php or just .html and doo check you are  running it through localhost ie. ur url is something like http://localhost/checklogin.php

Comment: Rahul - Thank you! I was running using physical path URL instead of [link](localhost/)

Comment: Your welcome :) well there are many other ways to thank here too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP isn't running. Assuming you are using Windows: Open your services (type services in your start menu) and browse to PHP. Start it.

Comment: Yes I'm using windows. I don't see service name PHP. But in the WAMP server ikon i can see all the services are running.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not parsed, assuming you are using Apache add the following two lines to your Apache conf and restart Apache.

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```